# logoff winxp with windowservice C#

Tags: c#, logoff

i want log off win xp by a condition in window service 
i use two method for them but not work 
pls help me
1.System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/l");

2.[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ExitWindowsEx(int uFlags, int dwReason);

Comment: What / how does it not work? Any errors? Unwanted behavior? Under what account is the service running?

Comment: Does your service run in the context of the correct user? Probably it will log off the user, which is running the service ...

Comment: not logoff when the condition is true